# PHP Login Script - The password is incorrect but the user exists?

Tags: php, forms, authentication

My username & password is correct but when i run this script and when i test my login i keep getting = "The password is incorrect but the user exists". Can anyone help?

Here is my Script;

```
<?php
include ("db.php");

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) == "1") {
    echo "You are already logged in. <a href=\"index.php\">Go home</a>";
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $username = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));
        $password = md5(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])));
        if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
            echo "Enter both fields.";
        } else {
            $userQ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = '{$username}'");
            if (mysql_num_rows($userQ) == 0) {
                echo "This user does not exist.";
            } else {
                $userA = mysql_fetch_array($userQ);
                if ($password !== $userA["password"]) {
                    echo "The password is incorrect but the user exists.";
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "1";
                    header("Location: index.php");
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
<form method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="25" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="20" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
</form>
 <?php
}
?>
```

Any Help would be great, i have just started to learn php and not sure if this code is correct.

Comment: Debug and check using `var_dump($password);` & `var_dump($userA["password"]);` and see what is the difference.

Comment: do not use `md5` on escaped string with `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: your problem is that you use `mysql_fetch_array` - it returns non associate array, and variable `$userA["password"]` is not set. Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead. Also I assume that this script is just for learning purposes, but mysql_* functions are deprecated. You should learn about mysqli_ or pdo

Comment: before the line, `echo "The password is incorrect but the user exists.";`, put this `var_dump(array($password, $userA["password"]));` and tell us result

Comment: You need to return assoc array and iterate through results. See my anser [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931238/php-login-script-the-password-is-incorrect-but-the-user-exists/23931516#23931516)

Comment: Please be aware that the mysql extension (supplying the mysql_ functions) has been deprecated since 2012, in favor of the mysqli and PDO extensions. It's use is highly discouraged. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$userA = mysql_fetch_array( $userQ );` this will return array. You need to iterate it and return associative array to check each record like;

```
.....
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $userQ)) {
    $userA = $row["password"];
}

if ( $password !== $userA["password"] ) {
    echo "The password is incorrect but the user exists.";
}
.....
```

There is iteration in above code, but it will always have one result, because username is unique(I think)

Comment: mysql_fetch_array will not return non-associative array unless you explicitly specify it. By default it returns both types of array. https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

I think **you may have multiple users with the same username**. Check your database for this. If not, then try to remove `mysql_real_escape_string()` before using md5 on it.

On a side note, if you are starting to leran PHP then don't use mysql functions anymore. Try to use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extensions. Mysql functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.